# Android Port bootloop due to non updatable apex or boringssl checks

Tags: android, boot

I am building LineageOS 18.1 for tecno kd7. I have system, system_ext, product & vendor paritions. The rom port I built is having a boot loop.

> Here is the [last_kmsg](https://gist.github.com/bretantonio/31b33601e3103fe5f3ad1bc366a5a883)

What is causing the boot loop?
I am suspecting these lines

```
[    1.802608]  (0)[354:apexd]apexd: This device does not support updatable APEX. Exiting
[    2.352523]  (0)[1:init]reboot: Restarting system with command 'boringssl-self-check-failed'
```

I just need direction on what I need to what is causing the phone to bootloop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same issue. The boringssl-self-test binary is using incorrect libcrypto.so library.
You can run the boringssl-self-test with strace and check for the issue.

In file : external/boringssl/selftest/boringssl_self_test.rc

```
service boringssl_self_test64_vendor /system/bin/strace -tt /vendor/bin/boringssl_self_test64
    setenv BORINGSSL_SELF_TEST_CREATE_FLAG true # Any nonempty value counts as true
    #reboot_on_failure reboot,boringssl-self-check-failed
    stdio_to_kmsg
    seclabel u:r:vendor_boringssl_self_test:s0
```